# Remotely Accessing Raspberry Pi from 20 meters away

Tags: audio, sensor, remote

I'd like to develop a system for prototyping purposes where I wirelessly remotely control a voice synthesizer and subsequently hear a person's answer into the system. I will be located approximately 15 or 20 meters away from the system.

I am hoping for some suggestions on what kind of technology people would use to achieve this kind of remote system.

I was thinking I could use a cellular connection (https://hologram.io/ comes up as an option) to send text strings to the system that it would then synthesize, but I'm not sure how to receive audio. A cellular connection seems overkill and too expensive. Perhaps that could just be a two-way radio? Since this is a prototype, ease-of-use and cheapness is prioritized over robustness or scalability.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should make sure wifi *isn't* viable for this before you bother looking into anything else, because "anything else" is going to be a lot less fun (so even if this means buying a couple of high power adapters with antennas, try to stick with wifi).

Answer (score 1):

Use a cat5 cable and a wired Ethernet connection.

Comment: Is there a wireless option? There probably will be a street separating the computer from the device.

Comment: An ordinary wireless router should work at that sort of distance.